# I'm not understanding how the Tower of Hanoi pegs are being updated properly

Tags: c++, recursion, towers-of-hanoi

Along the journey of teaching myself C++, I have encountered the Tower of Hanoi problem, a classic recursion exercise with which all programmers apparently have to grapple. I have slowly but surely been able to understand portions of how the solution works, with thanks to some of the answers here, but I've been stumped with an initial detail. I can't seem to understand how the target/destination peg is being updated before the very first move is being made. For instance, for one of the solutions I have studied:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void tower(int, int, int, int);

int main() {
    int num;
    
    cout << "Enter the number of disks: ";  cin >> num;
    tower(num, 1, 3, 2);
}

void tower(int numDisks, int initPeg, int tarPeg, int holdPeg) {
    if (numDisks > 0) {
        cout << "Target peg is: " << tarPeg << endl;
        
        tower(numDisks - 1, initPeg, holdPeg, tarPeg);
        cout << initPeg << "->" << tarPeg << endl;
        tower(numDisks - 1, holdPeg, tarPeg, initPeg);
    }
}
```

produces the following output:

```
Enter the number of disks: 3
Target peg is: 3
Target peg is: 2
Target peg is: 3
1->3
1->2
Target peg is: 2
3->2
1->3
Target peg is: 3
Target peg is: 1
2->1
2->3
Target peg is: 3
1->3
```

Where I have put in the target peg output statement to track how it updates during execution. First the target peg is 3, as per the call `tower(3, 1, 3, 2);` following input for `num = 3`. Then, inside `tower(3, ...)`, the function is called again, this time by `tower(numDisks - 1, initPeg, holdPeg, tarPeg);`, where the target peg is now seemingly specified to be peg 2. All good so far. Now, inside `tower(2, ...)`, the function seems to be called a third time by the same `tower(numDisks - 1, initPeg, holdPeg, tarPeg);`, yet the output clearly shows that `Target peg is: 3` again, not 2. This is the correct move, but it's not clear to me how the target peg updates to peg 3 in `tower(1, initPeg, holdPeg, tarPeg)`, since for the last call it specified the target peg to be peg 2.

Can anyone shed some light on this? I tried drawing out a trace for two disks, and everything looks good. But for three disks, I am obviously missing something. I hope the way I framed my issue makes sense.

Comment: Try printing all 3 disks by classification (target, init, & hold) so you can tell where target came from.

Comment: Draw the three pegs.  Draw the pegs and disks each time a move is made.

Comment: @ScottHunter I added output statements for each peg classification. I see that for the 2nd call which confuses me, the target is peg 3, init is peg 1, and hold is peg 2, like in the original call in main(). Hmm! But wasn't the 2nd call made in the same manner as call 1, which specifies target is peg 2, init is peg 1, and hold is peg 3?

Answer (score -1):

Here is the list of calls with their depth, with the moves.  I have omitted the calls with num==0 since they are no-ops.

```
tower( 3, 1, 3, 2 )
    tower( 2, 1, 2, 3 )
        tower( 1, 1, 3, 2 )
            1 -> 3
        1 -> 2
        tower( 1, 3, 2, 1 )
            3 -> 2
    1 -> 3
    tower( 2, 2, 3, 1 )
        tower( 1, 2, 1, 3 )
            2 -> 1
        2 -> 3
        tower( 1, 3, 2, 1 )
            1 -> 3
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very useful to follow along with. I guess what's confusing me is how the call third from the top has the arguments ( 1, 1, 3, 2 ) instead of ( 2, 1, 2, 3 ) again, because in the code it looks like tower ( 1, 1, 3, 2 ) is called inside tower ( 2, 1, 2, 3 ) by tower(numDisks - 1, initPeg, holdPeg, tarPeg), which was how we got tower ( 2, 1, 2, 3 ) to start with, if that makes any sense...

Comment: The first thing every new `tower` call does is call `tower` again with `numDisks` reduced.  Right?  So, you're going to go 3, then 2, then 1, then 0.  0 returns right away, which allows 1 to print its move and then call 0 again.

Comment: Right, I see how the `numDisks` variable decrements, but what causes the changes in the values for the pegs? That is, specifically, how do they go from `( ... , 1, 2, 3 )` back to to `( ... , 1, 3, 2)` when the order of the arguments `( numDisks - 1, initPeg, holdPeg, tarPeg )` remain the same? To my eye, `tower( 2, 1, 2, 3 )` and `tower( 1, 1, 3, 2 )` are called by the same statement `( numDisks - 1, initPeg, holdPeg, tarPeg )`, and I don't see how that results in the peg values shifting around. I DO see how `tower( 3, 1, 3, 2 )` results in `tower( 2, 1, 2, 3 )` however.

Comment: Because it's not the same "holdPeg".  When you're in `tower(2,1,2,3)`, you have initPeg=1, tarPeg=2, holdPeg=3.  Now I call `tower`, passing 1,initPeg,holdPeg,tarPeg, which is 1,1,3,2.  Those get passed to initPeg, tarPeg, holdPeg for this execution of the function.  So, the num=2 call passed 3 for the third parameter, which is now called "tarPeg".